# Count for Page views

Tags: visualforce

I have a question regarding Visualforce page views. If you have 10 visualforce pages on one page layout, does that count as 5 page views or just one. Help please :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 10 VF pages within one std page layout -- 5 ?? page views ?? Is there a typo here?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that...10 for 10 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every Visualforce page loaded, it counts as one view. If you have ten pages in a standard layout, that would be ten views.